# Could we remove old data in cardano-db-sync table (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I'm trying to improve the performance of cardano-db-sync's database by removing unused tables (truncate block table) and deleting old data from the tx_out table.

However after re-start the cardano-db-sync instance, seems that it is trying to re-fill old data even when I specified ledger-state from the snapshot state https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/syncing-and-rollbacks.md#ledger-state

```
2024-02-08 00:46:15 [db-sync-node:Info:165] [2024-02-07 17:46:15.39 UTC] Setting ConsistencyLevel to Unchecked
2024-02-08 00:46:15 [db-sync-node:Info:165] [2024-02-07 17:46:15.39 UTC] Starting chainSyncClient
2024-02-08 00:46:15 [db-sync-node:Info:165] [2024-02-07 17:46:15.39 UTC] Suggesting intersection points from memory: [] and from disk: []
2024-02-08 00:46:15 [db-sync-node:Info:165] [2024-02-07 17:46:15.40 UTC] Cardano.Db tip is at slot 16311, block 16312
2024-02-08 00:46:15 [db-sync-node:Info:172] [2024-02-07 17:46:15.40 UTC] Running Offline fetch thread
2024-02-08 00:46:15 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:46:15.40 UTC] Running DB thread
2024-02-08 00:46:15 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:46:15.96 UTC] Delaying delete of 16312 while rolling back to genesis. Applying blocks until a new block is found. The node is currently at Tip (SlotNo 54073215) 3888541878ad6584df95be05ca8816c32ba9976011c4cd5f0703a773cf61eaf8 (BlockNo 6918590)
2024-02-08 00:46:16 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:46:16.74 UTC] Found snapshot file for genesis
2024-02-08 00:46:16 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:46:16.74 UTC] Setting ConsistencyLevel to DBAheadOfLedger
2024-02-08 00:47:03 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:47:03.07 UTC] Received block which is not in the db with HeaderFields {headerFieldSlot = SlotNo 16312, headerFieldBlockNo = BlockNo 16313, headerFieldHash = a0bce776e49a0998e7acde647e7cb3a1794395abdb162d45c9c6f8ca16bdd049}. Time to restore consistency.
2024-02-08 00:47:03 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:47:03.08 UTC] Starting at epoch 0
2024-02-08 00:47:03 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:47:03.14 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 0, slot 16312, block 16313, hash a0bce776e49a0998e7acde647e7cb3a1794395abdb162d45c9c6f8ca16bdd049
2024-02-08 00:47:03 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:47:03.14 UTC] Setting ConsistencyLevel to Consistent
2024-02-08 00:48:00 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:48:00.26 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 0, slot 16999, block 17000, hash be219f7f8e2d4116ea718f34a7741eaf404c835ca0365b8f94426618b1a576a8
2024-02-08 00:48:04 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:48:04.48 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 0, slot 17999, block 18000, hash e711abf703ebb7aa7c1ad235dafacdb6880fbc4a5ff27f368046ee6a2975724d
2024-02-08 00:48:07 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:48:07.75 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 0, slot 18999, block 19000, hash 5c469c0c52cc8ad9b0d21d029c9aae75a8e0d82e686eb98e026c2ca71ee4fb21
2024-02-08 00:50:22 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:50:22.59 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 0, slot 19999, block 20000, hash 683be7324c47df71e2a234639a26d7747f1501addbba778636e66f3a18a46db7
2024-02-08 00:50:25 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:50:25.57 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 0, slot 20999, block 21000, hash e744980befb7bfbc2251efcce3897842545a766575bbfc931d42c875a9573dbf
2024-02-08 00:52:22 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:52:22.76 UTC] Took a ledger snapshot at /var/lib/cexplorer/21599-3bd04916b6-0.lstate. It took 0.034869166s.
2024-02-08 00:52:22 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:52:22.79 UTC] Persistant SQL Statement Cache size is 14
2024-02-08 00:52:22 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:52:22.79 UTC] 
2024-02-08 00:52:22 Cache Statistics:
2024-02-08 00:52:22   Stake Addresses: cache size: 0, hits: 0, misses: 0
2024-02-08 00:52:22   Pools: cache size: 0, hits: 0, misses: 0
2024-02-08 00:52:22   Datums: cache capacity: 50000, cache size: 0, hits: 0, misses: 0
2024-02-08 00:52:22   Multi Assets: cache capacity: 250000, cache size: 0, hits: 0, misses: 0
2024-02-08 00:52:22   Previous Block: hit rate: 49%, hits: 5273, misses: 5275
2024-02-08 00:52:22 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:52:22.79 UTC] Starting epoch 1
2024-02-08 00:52:22 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:52:22.80 UTC] insertABOBBoundary: epoch 1, hash 1941d944df546dea699791c318aeb9cc63b94e4cdb133d79856cda35bf7ecbb1
2024-02-08 00:59:32 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 17:59:32.52 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 1, slot 22013, block 22000, hash aad3ea4b6f582418364b4396e52d13742a20251c0c24bd00b87a166c89721da5
2024-02-08 01:02:33 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 18:02:33.09 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 1, slot 23013, block 23000, hash 66c167990b622ce28943a2bf518dbe810de7bb3356a8c8975ae0a1f9d621698f
2024-02-08 05:41:11 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-07 22:41:11.79 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 1, slot 24013, block 24000, hash 1a8ef01c1a92288b269638552c051a64d0a9b741abd37d78d7762070f9333810
2024-02-08 09:40:14 [db-sync-node:Info:171] [2024-02-08 02:40:14.70 UTC] insertByronBlock: epoch 1, slot 25013, block 25000, hash 37e44110466a04ee127106043c7b20fe7ccc19de01e7cf5da99a4d001865ed2c
```

So could we remove old data in cardano-db-sync's tables (PostgreSQL) safely?

Could anyone help, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, there is [this](https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/configuration.md#--prune-tx-out) command line flag `--prune-tx-out` which will do the pruning for you.

There are also other performance flags available that may be able to help you further, though some are experimental at the moment.